# Accessing all sharepoint list title in vs2010 through console application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Hi all I have written a code to retrieve the lists available in SharePoint using console application

My code is as follows

```
string strSite="http://dorababu:1904/";
SPSite spSite=new SPSite(strSite);
SPWeb spweb=spSite.RootWeb;
foreach(SPList objList in spweb.Lists)
{
    console.WriteLine(objList.Title);
}
spweb.Dispose();
spSite.Dispose();
consol.ReadLine();
```

Can some one help me this is not showing the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Would go for using the Client Object Model for this since you're using SharePoint 2010. With this code you can load the SharePoint content from outside the server.

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://tests");
var lists = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists;
ctx.Load(lists);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var list in lists)
  Console.WriteLine(list.Title);

Console.ReadKey();
```

You need to add the following references for this to work:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
```